# how to make same size descriptors for all images

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, svm, surf

Can any one please tell me how to make descriptor's are of fix size ? because we may get different number of descriptors from different images
`For example` 
If i have image of 450*550 and i am apply surf feature on it , than surf extract keypoints from it and than it extract descriptors from it , for example ,It extract `10 descriptors` of keypoints from `450*550 image` , than it read again an image and its size it 750*880 , so surf extract keypoints from it and than descriptors , for example this time it extract `20 descriptors` from this image , Now What i want to do is , i want that whatever the size of image , the size size of descriptors should be same , like it should take 10 descriptors from both images, so in case of many images it should select the minimum size of descriptor and extract only that descriptors from all images and leave others , Or i define the size and it ignore the images who descriptors are below or above that size

```
extractor.compute( tmplate_img, keypoints, descriptors);
my_img=descriptors.reshape(1,1);
```

I want to make the same size of descriptors for all the images when i run it through loop and which size of descriptor is better for getting better result , descriptors is MAT.

Thanks

Comment: which detector and descriptor are you using?

Comment: @GiLevi Sift and Surf both

Comment: This is a very bad question. You need to start by describing what you have done, what OpenCV functions/classes you are using, and what you are trying to achieve in a concise way. Don't assume that other people are working on the exact same issue. Think about the readers when you write your question.

Comment: @Bee I try to make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to keep the top M keypoints that have the largest response:

```
bool compareFunction(KeyPoint p1, KeyPoint p2) {return p1.response>p2.response;}
//The function retains the stongest M keypoints in kp
void RetainBestKeypoints(vector<KeyPoint>  &kp, int M)
{
    vector<KeyPoint>  sortedkp;

    sort(kp.begin(),kp.end(),compareFunction);
    if (kp.size()>M)
            kp.erase(kp.begin()+M,kp.end());
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the size of descriptors of all the images same and save their size of all images , i don't want that i got 10 descriptos for one image , and 15 for 2nd , and 20 for 3rd and so on , i want the descriptors of all the images to the same size , If i get the largest/maximum descriptors to the fix size e.g 30 and i get the descriptors of all other images is 20 maximum so it raise the same problem

Comment: Do you mean the dimension of the descriptor vector? I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: I think I understood your question. Say you want 10 descriptors from each image. Extract more then 10 keypoints from the image, but keep only the top 10 using the code I pasted above and then extract descriptors for those keypoints.

Comment: May i ask why you take two keypoints as argument ? in compare function ?

Comment: I'm comparing them according to their response. I'm keeping the M keypoints with the largest response and throwing all the others away.

Comment: +1 , what if `if (kp.size()<M)` ? should i use it as `elseif(kp.size()<M)` ignore the image ?

Comment: i add the other condition so it would helpful for others , thanks